# Allow squid transparent proxy on non standard http ports

Tags: networking, proxy, squid, transparentproxy

Please bear as I am totally new to squid.

I need to setup a squid transparent proxy to for NAT and allow URL filtering in AWS. I followed this[AWS Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-add-dns-filtering-to-your-nat-instance-with-squid/) AWS link and everything works as expected. However, the proxy works only for sites that are listening to 80 or 443. Now I need to allow some non standard ports like 8080 as some clients need to talk to servers listening on them.

Below is the current squid conf.

```
visible_hostname squid
cache deny all

# Log format and rotation
logformat squid %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %ssl::>sni %Sh/%<a %mt
logfile_rotate 10
debug_options rotate=10

# Handling HTTP requests
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
http_access allow allowed_http_sites

# Handling HTTPS requests
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem ssl-bump intercept
acl SSL_port port 443
http_access allow SSL_port
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump terminate step2 all
#below line is custom- not from aws. This is to allow self signed certs on trusted sites
sslproxy_cert_error allow allowed_https_sites
http_access deny all
```

How do I allow 8080 also here ? Note that this is a transparent proxy, so I do not want to change any settings at client side.

I added the following lines to the conf, but it seems not working.

```
acl SSL_ports port 8080
acl Safe_ports port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just figured out what to do. It is not required to change anything in the conf file. Instead just had to add an iptables rule as follows.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
```

The required rules for 80 and 443 were given in the AWS documentation itself.